# absolute position not outside document flow if in overflow auto parent

Tags: html, css, dom, css-position

Why does a `position:absolute` element affect the document flow when it's parent is `position:relative` inside a parent which is `overflow:auto`? (Example below)

This seems to run counter to expected behavior:

> The element is removed from the normal document flow; no space is created for the element in the page layout" [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute).

`div.a` should always only be 100px tall, and never need vertical scrolling, since it has only one line of text and it's child (`div.b`) has a height of 0. This indeed is the case, and we can see `div.c`'s positioning outside the normal document flow.

However, if `overflow:auto` is applied to `div.a` (like the example below), `div.a` accommodates `div.c`'s height (a height on a position absolute element which is not supposed to be in the normal document flow) by supplying a scroll bar. Why? `div.b` still has a height of 0, and `div.c` shows no green background through the transparency.

```css
.a {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;  /* TOGGLE THIS LINE */
  background-color: pink;
}

.b {
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
}

.c {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  height: 500px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  I should only be 100px tall
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">
      I am position absolute with a height of 500px
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4v7px6wL/1/)

Answer (score 2):

The absolute-positioned element will be pulled out of the document flow BUT browser will always make it possible for you to access the element by providing scrollbars UNLESS there are "overflow:hidden"-s applied to wrappers

To clear it up a bit: Even the overflown content will be considered as a part of the document by the Browser and it will expand the margins of the view so it includes all the elements inside the view. The default value of `overflow` is set to `visible`.